# Call function on notebook crash / shutdown / reset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

my question is simple

Is there a way of implementing either a callback function, either a javascript function, or a curl postdata to url once the notebook crashes / restarts / becomes idle ?

That would be hyper convenient for my purposes

Thanks a lot for any clue, enlightment, comment, notice ;)
Regards

Comment: Did u get any solution

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely in Javascript, as that will require to read from the Operating System(OS) and that is not allowed due to security. 
Not sure in other languages.